# PostgreSQL - insert rows based on select from another table, and update an FK in that table with the newly inserted rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing a data migration between two tables (splitting out a related table). The existing table is `reminders`, and it has a `start` column and a newly-added `dateset_id` column pointing to a new `dateset` table, which also has a `start` column. For every row in `reminders`, I want to `INSERT` a new row in `dateset` with the `start` value copied over, and `UPDATE` the corresponding row in `reminders` with the newly-inserted `dateset` ID.

Here's the SQL I tried:

```
WITH inserted_datesets AS (
  INSERT INTO dateset (start)
  SELECT start FROM reminder
  RETURNING reminder.id AS reminder_id, id AS dateset_id
)
UPDATE reminder
SET dateset_id = ids.dateset_id
FROM inserted_datesets AS ids
WHERE reminder.id = ids.reminder_id
```

I get an error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "reminder"`, because I'm including the `reminder.id` column in the `RETURNING` clause, but not actually selecting it for the insert. This makes sense, but I can't figure out how to modify the query to do what I need. Is there a totally different approach I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways to solve the problem.

**1. temporarily add a column**

As others mentioned, the straight-forward way is to temporarily add a column `reminder_id` to the `dateset`. Populate it with original `IDs` from `reminder` table. Use it to join `reminder` with the `dateset` table. Drop the temporary column.

**2. when start is unique**

If values of the `start` column is unique it is possible to do it without extra column by joining `reminder` table with the `dateset` table on the `start` column.

```
INSERT INTO dateset (start)
SELECT start FROM reminder;

WITH
CTE_Joined
AS
(
    SELECT
        reminder.id AS reminder_id
        ,reminder.dateset_id AS old_dateset_id
        ,dateset.id AS new_dateset_id
    FROM
        reminder
        INNER JOIN dateset ON dateset.start = reminder.start
)
UPDATE CTE_Joined
SET old_dateset_id = new_dateset_id
;
```

**3. when start is not unique**

It is possible to do it without temporary column even in this case. The main idea is the following. Let's have a look at this example:

We have two rows in `reminder` with the same `start` value and IDs 3 and 7:

```
reminder
id    start         dateset_id
3     2015-01-01    NULL
7     2015-01-01    NULL
```

After we insert them into the `dateset`, there will be new IDs generated, for example, 1 and 2:

```
dateset
id    start
1     2015-01-01
2     2015-01-01
```

It doesn't really matter how we link these two rows. The end result could be

```
reminder
id    start         dateset_id
3     2015-01-01    1
7     2015-01-01    2
```

or

```
reminder
id    start         dateset_id
3     2015-01-01    2
7     2015-01-01    1
```

Both of these variants are correct. Which brings us to the following solution.

Simply insert all rows first.

```
INSERT INTO dateset (start)
SELECT start FROM reminder;
```

Match/join two tables on `start` column knowing that it is not unique. "Make it" unique by adding `ROW_NUMBER` and joining by two columns. It is possible to make the query shorter, but I spelled out each step explicitly:

```
WITH
CTE_reminder_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,start
        ,dateset_id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY start ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM reminder
)
,CTE_dateset_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,start
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY start ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM dateset
)
,CTE_Joined
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_reminder_rn.id AS reminder_id
        ,CTE_reminder_rn.dateset_id AS old_dateset_id
        ,CTE_dateset_rn.id AS new_dateset_id
    FROM
        CTE_reminder_rn
        INNER JOIN CTE_dateset_rn ON 
            CTE_dateset_rn.start = CTE_reminder_rn.start AND
            CTE_dateset_rn.rn = CTE_reminder_rn.rn
)
UPDATE CTE_Joined
SET old_dateset_id = new_dateset_id
;
```

I hope it is clear from the code what it does, especially when you compare it to the simpler version without `ROW_NUMBER`. Obviously, the complex solution will work even if `start` is unique, but it is not as efficient, as a simple solution.

This solution assumes that `dateset` is empty before this process.

Comment: How does `2.` work? It seems this variant can only work if CTEs can be treated as views and be updated. I think at the moment this is not possible in postgres.

Comment: @matthiaskrull, looks like you are right. I was using SQL Server syntax and I don't have Postgres at hand to check. In Postgres you'll need to use the `FROM` clause in the [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html) statement to join tables.

Answer (score 7):

### Update based on changes in Postgres:

Using INSERT RETURNING in subqueries is, according to the documentation, supported, for Postgres versions 9.1 and after.  The hypothetical DML subquery in the original answer should work for Postgres >= 9.1:

```
UPDATE reminder SET dateset_id = (
    INSERT INTO dateset (start)
    VALUES (reminder.start)
    RETURNING dateset.id));
```

### Original answer:

Here's another way of doing it, distinct from the 3 ways Vladimir suggested so far.

A temporary function will let you read the id of the new rows created as well as other values in the query:

```
--minimal demonstration schema
CREATE TABLE dateset (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  start TIMESTAMP
  -- other things here...
);

CREATE TABLE reminder (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  start TIMESTAMP,
  dateset_id INTEGER REFERENCES dateset(id)
  -- other things here...
);

--pre-migration data
INSERT INTO reminder (start) VALUES ('2014-02-14'), ('2014-09-06'), ('1984-01-01'), ('2014-02-14');

--all at once
BEGIN;

CREATE FUNCTION insertreturning(ts TIMESTAMP) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
    INSERT INTO dateset (start)
    VALUES (ts)
    RETURNING dateset.id;
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

UPDATE reminder SET dateset_id = insertreturning(reminder.start);

DROP FUNCTION insertreturning(TIMESTAMP);

ALTER TABLE reminder DROP COLUMN start;

END;
```

This approach to the problem suggested itself after I realized that writing `INSERT ... RETURNING` as a subquery would solve the issue; although `INSERT`s are not allowed as subqueries, calls to functions certainly are.

Intriguingly, this suggests that DML subqueries that return values might be broadly useful.  If they were possible, we would just write:

```
UPDATE reminder SET dateset_id = (
    INSERT INTO dateset (start)
    VALUES (reminder.start)
    RETURNING dateset.id));
```

Comment: Oh, very nice! Ok, at this point I have no idea who to give the bounty to - This is the fourth good answer. Wish I could give it to everyone who answered.

Comment: I think I'm going to give it to Vladimir, just for suggesting the widest range of options, including several that don't require adding/dropping a temporary column or function. But this is a very nice answer - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can only return columns using RETURNING from the INSERT-part, not from the selected table.
So, if you are willing to add a column *reminder_id* to your dateset-table,

```
    ALTER TABLE dateset ADD COLUMN reminder_id integer;
```

the following statement will work:

```
WITH inserted_datesets AS (
  INSERT INTO dateset (start, reminder_id)
  SELECT start, id FROM reminder
  RETURNING reminder_id, id AS dateset_id
)
UPDATE reminder
SET dateset_id = ids.dateset_id
FROM inserted_datesets AS ids
WHERE id = reminder_id
```

**Only if** the values of the column *start* in *reminders* **are all unique**, the following 2 statements will work as well:

```
INSERT INTO dateset(start) SELECT start FROM reminder;
UPDATE reminder SET dateset_id = (SELECT id FROM dateset WHERE start=reminder.start);
```

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks! Wish I could award the bounty to multiple answers, but since I have to pick one, I'm going to go with Vladimir's, for having the widest range of options, including one that works when start is not unique, without needing a temp column.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you can only return columns that are present in the table you insert into. You could solve it by giving the table dataset an additional column into which you insert reminder.id so you can return it.

Then after the migration you can drop that column.