# Split Table into many to many relationship: Data Migration

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, database-migration

I am wondering how best to migrate my data when splitting a Table into a many to many relationship. I've made a simplified example and I'll also post some of the solutions I have come up with.
I am using a Postgresql Database.

**Before Migration**

Table Person

```
ID       Name        Pet        PetName
1        Follett     Cat        Garfield
2        Rowling     Hamster    Furry
3        Martin      Cat        Tom
4        Cage        Cat        Tom
```

**After Migration**

Table Person

```
ID       Name
1        Follett
2        Rowling
3        Martin
4        Cage
```

Table Pet

```
ID       Pet        PetName
6        Cat        Garfield
7        Hamster    Furry
8        Cat        Tom
9        Cat        Tom
```

Table PersonPet

```
FK_Person     FK_Pet
1             6
2             7
3             8
4             9
```

Notes:

- I will specifically duplicate entries in the Pet Table (because in my case - due to other related data - one of them might still be editable by the customer while the other might not).
- There is no column that uniquely identifies a "Pet" record.
- For me it does not matter whether 3-8 and 4-9 are linked in the PersonPet table or 3-9 and 4-8.
- Also I omitted all code that handles the schema changes of the tables as this is - in my understanding - irrelevant for this question.

**My Solutions**

1. When creating the Pet Table temporarily add a column containing the id of the Person Table that was used to create this entry.

```
    ALTER TABLE Pet ADD COLUMN IdPerson INTEGER;

    INSERT INTO Pet (Pet, PetName, IdPerson)
    SELECT Pet, PetName, ID
    FROM Person;

    INSERT INTO PersonPet (FK_Person, FK_Pet)
    SELECT ID, IdPerson
    FROM Pet;

    ALTER TABLE Pet DROP Column IdPerson;
```

2. avoid temporarily modifying the Pet table

```
    INSERT INTO Pet (Pet, PetName)
    SELECT Pet, PetName
    FROM Person;

    WITH
      CTE_Person
      AS
      (SELECT
        Id, Pet, PetName
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pet, PetName ORDER BY Id) AS row_number
      FROM Person
      )
      ,CTE_Pet
      AS
      (SELECT
        Id, Pet, PetName
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pet, PetName ORDER BY Id) AS row_number
      FROM Pet
      )
      ,CTE_Joined
      AS
      (SELECT
        CTE_Person.Id AS Person_Id,
        CTE_Pet.Id AS Pet_Id
      FROM
        CTE_Person
        INNER JOIN CTE_Pet ON
        CTE_Person.Pet = CTE_Pet.Pet
        CTE_Person.PetName = CTE_Pet.PetName
        AND CTE_Person.row_number = CTE_Pet.row_number
      )
      INSERT INTO PersonPet (FK_Person, FK_Pet)
      SELECT Person_Id, Pet_Id from CTE_Joined;
```

**Questions**

1. Are both solutions correct? (I have tested the second solution and the result does seem to be correct, but I might have missed some corner case)
2. What are the advantages/disadvantages of the two solution?
3. Is there an easier way of doing the same data migration? (For my curiosity I would also be interested in answers that slightly modify my constraints (e.g. no duplicate entries in the Pet table), but please indicate which ones :) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution to achieve effect you described (in my opinion the simplest one; without any CTE-s or additional columns):

```
create table Pet as
    select
        Id,
        Pet,
        PetName
    from 
        Person;

create table PersonPet as
    select
        Id as FK_Person,
        Id as FK_Pet
    from
        Person;

create sequence PetSeq;
update PersonPet set FK_Pet=nextval('PetSeq'::regclass);
update Pet p set Id=FK_Pet from PersonPet pp where p.Id=pp.FK_Person;

alter table Pet alter column Id set default nextval('PetSeq'::regclass);
alter table Pet add constraint PK_Pet primary key (Id);
alter table PersonPet add constraint FK_Pet foreign key (FK_Pet) references Pet(Id);
```

We are simply using existing person id as a temporary id for pet unless we generate one using sequence.

**Edit**

It's also possible to use my approach having schema changes already done:

```
insert into Pet(Id, Pet, PetName)
    select
        Id,
        Pet,
        PetName
    from
        Person;

insert into PersonPet(FK_Person, FK_Pet)
    select
        Id,
        Id
    from
        Person;

select setval('PetSeq'::regclass, (select max(Id) from Person));
```

Comment: hi. I like the solution, it looks really neat! In my case this is not really an option since the changes to the schema are handled in a different place.

Comment: I edited my post and included solution for situation where schema is already modified. Basically all we have to do is to adjust pet sequence and voilà :).

Answer (score 4):

You can overcome the limitation of having to add an extra column to the pets table by inserting first into the foreign key table and then into the pets table.  This allows establishing what the mapping is first and then filling in the details in a second pass.

```
INSERT INTO PersonPet
SELECT ID, nextval('pet_id_seq'::regclass) as PetID
FROM Person;

INSERT INTO Pet
SELECT FK_Pet, Pet, Petname
FROM Person join PersonPet on (ID=FK_Person);
```

This can be combined into a single statement using the common table expression mechanisms outlined by Vladimir in his answer:

```
WITH
fkeys AS
(
  INSERT INTO PersonPet
    SELECT ID, nextval('pet_id_seq'::regclass) as PetID
    FROM Person
  RETURNING FK_Person as PersonID, FK_Pet as PetID
)
INSERT INTO Pet
SELECT f.PetID, p.Pet, p.Petname
FROM Person p join fkeys f on (p.ID=f.PersonID);
```

As far as advantages and disadvantages:

Your solution #1:

- Is more computationally efficient, it consists of two scan operations, no joins and no sorts.
- Is less space efficient because it requires storing extra data in the Pet table.  In Postgres that space is not recovered on DROP column (but you could recover it with CREATE TABLE AS / DROP TABLE).
- Could cause issues if you are doing this repeatedly, e.g. adding/dropping a column regularly, because you will run into the Postgres max column limit.

The solution I outlined is less computationally efficient than your solution #1 because it requires the join, but is more efficient than your solution #2.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your both solutions are correct. They remind me of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28408204/4116017).

Few notes.

First variant with adding an extra column `PersonID` into the `Pet` table could be done in a single query using `RETURNING` clause.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/514ce/2/0)

```
-- Add temporary PersonID column to Pet

WITH
CTE_Pets
AS
(
    INSERT INTO Pet (PersonID, Pet, PetName)
    SELECT Person.ID, Person.Pet, Person.PetName
    FROM Person
    RETURNING ID AS PetID, PersonID
)
INSERT INTO PersonPet (FK_Person, FK_Pet)
SELECT PersonID, PetID
FROM CTE_Pets
;

-- Drop temporary PersonID column
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `RETURNING` clause in `INSERT` in Postgres is limited to returning columns only from the destination table, i.e. only those values that were actually inserted. For example, in MS SQL Server `MERGE` can return values from both source and destination tables making this kind of tasks easy, but I can't find anything similar in Postgres.

So, the second variant without adding an explicit `PersonID` column into the `Pet` table requires joining original `Person` with new `Pet` to map old `PersonID` to new `PetID`.

If there can be duplicates as in your example (`Cat Tom`), then use `ROW_NUMBER` to assign sequential numbers to distinguish duplicate rows as you've shown in the question.

If there are no such duplicates, then you can simplify the mapping and get rid of `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
INSERT INTO Pet (Pet, PetName)
SELECT Pet, PetName
FROM Person;

INSERT INTO PersonPet (FK_Person, FK_Pet)
SELECT
    Person.ID AS FK_Person
    ,Pet.ID AS FK_Pet
FROM
    Person
    INNER JOIN Pet ON
        Person.Pet = Pet.Pet AND
        Person.PetName = Pet.PetName
;
```

---

I see one advantage of the first method.

If you store explicitly `PersonID` in the `Pet` table it will be easier to perform this kind of migration in several steps, in batches. The second variant works OK when `PersonPet` is empty, but if you have migrated a batch of rows already it may become tricky to filter needed rows.